# export 'default'.'greaterThan' (imported as 'Animated') was not found in 'react-native-reanimated'

Tags: react-native

[WARNING in ./node_modules/@react-navigation/drawer/lib/module/views/legacy/Overlay.js:11:4
export 'default'.'greaterThan' (imported as 'Animated') was not found in 'react-native-reanimated' (possible exports: FlatList, Image, ScrollView, Text, View, addWhitelistedNativeProps, addWhitelistedUIProps, createAnimatedComponent)
9 |   cond,
10 |   greaterThan,

> 11 | } = Animated;
> |    ^
> 12 |
> 13 | const interpolate: typeof interpolateNode =
> 14 |   interpolateNode ?? interpolateDeprecated;WARNING in ./node_modules/@react-navigation/drawer/lib/module/views/legacy/Overlay.js:11:4
> export 'default'.'greaterThan' (imported as 'Animated') was not found in 'react-native-reanimated' (possible exports: FlatList, Image, ScrollView, Text, View, addWhitelistedNativeProps, addWhitelistedUIProps, createAnimatedComponent)
> 9 |   cond,
> 10 |   greaterThan,
> 11 | } = Animated;
> |    ^
> 12 |
> 13 | const interpolate: typeof interpolateNode =
> 14 |   interpolateNode ?? interpolateDeprecated;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyB3K.jpg)